# Moving cursor in bash with keyboard

Tags: linux, bash

Say I have a bash window like this:

```
# cmd 1
output of cmd 1
# cmd 2
output of cmd 2
# (cursor here)
```

Is it possible to move the cursor (with keyboard only) to previous line, say output of cmd 1, copy some words and paste them to the  current cursor position?

I.e. Is there a bash equivalent of the following command in vim:

```
kkkvllyGp
```

Thanks

Comment: sounds like a feature of the terminal emulator moreso than a bash one

Comment: Did you want something programmatic, or something interactive?  If just interactive, in most X-style terminals you can highlight output with the left mouse button and paste it with the middle mouse button (or both left&right clicked together if you lack a middle mouse button).  For a programmatic method, see my answer below.  If you lack mouseability but want an interactive method, 'that other guy's response about `screen` is pretty reasonable.

Answer (score 2):

You can use GNU `screen`.

In a screen session, <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>esc</kbd> enters copy mode, where you can move the cursor with the arrow keys, mark start and end points with space, and then paste with <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>a</kbd>, <kbd>]</kbd>

Comment: Not really like the GNU screen solution, have to start a session for it. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

`bash` has no knowledge of what the terminal displays.  If you want to capture the output of `cmd 1` and do something with it, you either need to redirect it to a file or capture it in a variable.  eg:

```
cmd 1 > cmd1out.txt
```

or

```
CMD1OUT="$(cmd 1)"
```

Then, once you've captured that output within the shell, you can use it as you like.  For example, to execute that output directly as another command, you could do

```
source cmd1out.txt    #if you sent it to a file
```

or

```
eval "$CMD1OUT"       #if you captured it in a variable
```